# Non-integer moment of Brownian motion integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion. For some non-integer $\alpha>0$, what is
$$
 \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^x e^{B_t} dt \right)^{\alpha} \right]?
$$

**Notes**
For the integer $\alpha$, I can solve this problem easily by Fubini Theorem as follows:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^x \cdots \int_0^x e^{B_{t_1,}+\cdots+B_{t_\alpha}} dt_1 \cdots dt_{\alpha} \right] = \int_0^x \cdots \int_0^x \mathbb{E}\left[e^{B_{t_1,}+\cdots +B_{t_\alpha}}\right] dt_1 \cdots dt_{\alpha}.
$$
The term $\mathbb{E}\left[e^{B_{t_1,}+\cdots +B_{t_\alpha}}\right]$ can be easily obtained using the moment generating function of Gaussian.

This question is derived from the other question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363209/expectation-of-stochastic-integral-which-is-similar-to-the-incomplete-gamma-func).
It would be generalized to what is $\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^x X_t dt \right)^{\alpha} \right]$ for some stochastic process $X_t$?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you would need to know the complete probability distribution of the variable $\int_{0}^xe^{B_t}dt$, which is formally an infinite sum of i.i log-normal-distributed variables. Since the sum of two independent lognormal variables is not log-normal distributed, I think it is very hard to calculate the general case explicitly. If you have an explicit formula for integer $\alpha$ in terms of functions that can be analytically continued, you may be able to conjecture a formula, but it sounds very hard since the integral you're trying to compute must be trimmed to the right time ordered wedge